# jsf message severity

Tags: jsf, message

How do I able to fetch all the messages with SEVERITY is ERROR only.
I tried:

```
Iterator<FacesMessage> messages = facesContext.getMessages(clientId);
while (messages.hasNext()){
    if(messages.next().getSeverity().toString()=="ERROR 2")System.out.println(messages);
}
```

Is this th right way? It doesnot intercept messages with ERROR severity.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The comparison is wrong. You cannot (reliably) compare Strings on its content with `==`. When comparing objects with `==`, it would only return `true` if they are of the same **reference**, not *value* as you seem to expect. Objects needs to be compared with `Object#equals()`.

But you can compare **constants** with `==`. The [`FacesMessage.Severity`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html#field_summary) values are all static constants. You should rather just compare `Severity` with `Severity`. Also the sysout is wrong, it is printing the iterator instead of the sole message.

This should work:

```
Iterator<FacesMessage> messages = facesContext.getMessages(clientId);
while (messages.hasNext()) {
    FacesMessage message = messages.next();
    if (message.getSeverity() == FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually, only enum constants are consistent to compare with ==, objects can fail. Use severity1.getOrdinal() == severity2.getOrdinal() instead.